# Position fixed messes up layout

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Preview:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/54191672/theme/index.html

Originally I tried togo with bootstrap's affix plugin but when scrolling it glitches:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/54191672/affix/index.html

I've been so stuck on this and Im not sure why it messes it up. All I want is a fixed sidebar while I scroll down the images smoothly.

```
  <div id="sidr" class="sidebar col-xs-2 col-md-3">
        <div class="sidebar-inner-container">
            <div class="logo-container">
                <img src="images/logo.png" alt="" class="logo">
            </div><!-- /.logo-container -->
            <nav class="main-nav">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="journal.html">Journal</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <footer class="main-footer">
                <div class="social">
                    <a class="social-icon icon-facebook" href="#"></a>
                    <a class="social-icon icon-googleplus" href="#"></a>
                    <a class="social-icon icon-behance" href="#"></a>
                    <a class="social-icon icon-rss" href="#"></a>
                </div>
            </footer>
        </div><!-- /.sidebar-inner-container -->
    </div><!-- /.sidebar -->
```

CSS:

```
.sidebar {
  background: #fff;
  padding-top: 65px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  box-shadow: 5px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please include your code, instead of screenshots. Otherwise we are just guessing at what's going on.

Comment: This is a live version of the website, not screenshots.

Comment: where is Position fixed ?? in above code, include complete code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

being that youre using Position fixed for your sidebar youre gonna need to give your main element a margin-left with the same width as the sidebar element:

try this CSS:

```
.main-content{
    margin-left: 400px;
}
```